# How to add ssclass to a dynamically created button in asp.net?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, button

I am Creating a Button Dynamically in Asp.net how can i add existing css style to the dynamic button
i want to change the button color on Mouse hover and Mouse focus
i tried in so many ways like:

```
Button btn1 = new Button();              
btn1.CssClass = "btnmbl1";
btn1.Attributes.Add("href", "../Styles/style.css");
btn1.Attributes["CssClass"] = "btnmbl1";
//btn1.Attributes.Add("CssClass", "btnmbl1");
btn1.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
btn1.Attributes.Add("rel", "btnmbl1");
```

but no luck plz help me
Thank u

Answer (score 1):

Assign `class` name to to `CssClass` property.

```
btn1.CssClass = "btnmbl1";
```

or use `class` instead of `CssClass` in `Add` method

```
btn1.Attributes.Add("class", "btnmbl1");
```

Comment: No working does not give any clue what is happening, check the generated html to see of class is being assigned to button or not?

Comment: The class is not adding to attributes collections

Comment: Get the generated html from browser

Comment: generated Html for btn1 from browser is<td align="Left" height="30px"><input type="submit" name="ctl04" value="" class="btnmbl1" /></td> but it is not applying to the button

Comment: You need to add class to your page in order to see effect, see, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tbze79kd(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thank you I got it by putting <link href="MyStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />